# How to modify css by class name in selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning how to use Selenium in `python` and I try to modify a `css` style on http://www.google.com. 
For example, the `<span class="gbts"> ....</span>` on that page.
I would like to modify the `gbts` class.

```
browser.execute_script("q = document.getElementById('gbts');" + "q.style.border = '1px solid red';")
```

Is there an API method called `getElementByClass('gbts')` ?

Comment: Why are you attempting to do that? This is nothing to do with Selenium, it's more of a Javascript question.

Comment: @Aran, why i can modify css by id but not by class. Is there any other methods to modify by class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking how to get an element by it's CSS class using JavaScript. Nothing to do with Selenium *really*.

Regardless, you have a few options. You can first grab the element using Selenium (so here, yes, Selenium is relevant):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("gbts")
```

With a reference to this element already, it's then very easy to give it a border:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.border = '1px solid red';")
```

(Note, the `arguments[0]`)

If you really must use JavaScript and JavaScript alone, then you are very limited. This is because there is no `getElementByClassName` function within JavaScript. Only `getElementsByClassName` which means it would return a *list* of elements that match a given class.

So you must specifically target what element within the list, that is returned, you want to change. If I wanted to change the *very first* element that had a class of `gbts`, I'd do:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('gbts')[0].style.border = '1px solid red';")
```

I would suggest you go for the first option, which means you have Selenium do the leg work for you.

Comment: I get this error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

Comment: Figured it out. I had to pass another parameter to execute_script which was element

Comment: This answer shows how to add specific CSS properties, but does not address the original question about adding a class.

Comment: @WEFX that's because the question is not how to **add** a class, but rather how to **get it by class**. As I say, nothing to do with Selenium really. The question is more JS than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Another pure JavaScript option which you may find gives you more flexibility is to use `document.querySelector()`.

Not only will it automatically select the first item from the results set for you, but additionally say you have multiple elements with that class name, but you know that there is only one element with that class name within a certain parent element, you can restrict the search to within that parent element, e.g. `document.querySelector("#parent-div .gbts")`.

See the [(Mozilla documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) for more info.